# R - List of lists as input argument in a function

Tags: r, list, nested-lists, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using the "dag" function from gRbase package in conjuction with plot to create some DAG's.

In the "dag" help page I see this in the arguments:

> x,     A list containing a generating class for a graph, see examples
>   below

In the examples below I see something like this:

```
dagr <- dag(c("me","ve"),c("me","al"),c("ve","al"),c("al","an"),c("al","st"),c("an","st"))
```

And consequently when I execute this code, it works and gives me the graph:

```
> plot(dag(c("A", "B"), c("B", "C")))
```

Why when I create my own list I get the following error?

```
> mylist <- list();
> mylist[1] <- list(c("A", "B"))
> mylist[2] <- list(c("B", "C"))
> mylist
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "B" "C"

> plot(dag(mylist))
Error in plot(dag(mylist)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': Error in .ftM2other(ft, W, V, edgemode, "graphNEL") : 
  Node names in 'ft' must be contained in 'V'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function expects several arguments, 
but you provide a single argument (a list).
You can use `do.call` in this case.

```
do.call(dag, mylist)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works.
In the meanwhile, I solved the problem by using a Nx2 matrix directly against the ftM2graphNEL function.